# Reducing memory footprint of my application

Tags: c#, .net, memory, memory-management

I am developing C# application with limited memory. I initialize a large number of objects like the ones below which have several properties which takes up around 20MB. How can I reduce the amount of memory used by my application.

```
public class BusStop
{
    private List<BusRoute> busRoutes = new List<BusRoute>();
    private string name;
    // ... Other properties omitted like Code, ID, Location, etc.

    public BusStop(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<BusStop> BusRoutes
    {
        get { return this.busRoutes; }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.name; }
    }
}

public class BusRoute
{
    private List<BusStop> busStops = new List<BusStop>();
    private string name;
    // ... Other properties omitted like Code, ID, Location, etc.

    public BusStop(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<BusStop> BusStops
    {
        get { return this.busStops; }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.name; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I  couldn't help noticing that you store BusRoute for every stop and BusStop for every route, isn't that a waste of memory? Wouldn't a linklist be more effective in your case, since every node is a BusStop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple point - do not load them into memory. Wasteful and totally uinneeded. hey, when I order a supertanker full of oil to replace the oil in my car  most of it is waste, what can i do - well, order only as much oil as you need, not a supertanker full.

Databases are there for a reason, you know.

Answer (score 2):

Either don't load them into memory, or only load them when you need them, or use a Flyweight pattern to put in common some properties.

Maybe a proxy pattern could also be useful in some way, because you cant afford to load/unload such large objects.

Just throwing in ideas, but 20mb objects is pretty insane! Do you have images and stuff like that? Or only properties? Because from what I see, I can imagine you could share at least some properties/objects!

Factory pattern could also come in handy in order to limit useless instantiations, and enable you to share instances quite easily!

Resources :

[Factory pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method)

[Proxy pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/proxy)

[Flyweight pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/flyweight)

[Prototype pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/prototype)

Answer (score 1):

Try Lazy Initialization: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997286.aspx